# How do you define an empty variable to store the value of a File struct?

Tags: go

I am trying to figure out a way to declare an empty variable to store the return  values of `os.Create` and `os.Open`. Code:

```
func main() {

  var path = "list.txt"
  // Some attempts:
  // var file File{}
  // var file *File

  // Check if file exists
  var _, err = os.Stat(path)

  // If new file, create it
  if os.IsNotExist(err) {
    var file, err = os.Create(path)

    // If file exists, open it
  } else {
    var file, err = os.Open(path)
  }

  // Check errors opening and creating file
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
  }

  // Defer closing file
  defer file.Close()

}
```

Both attempts result in the following error:

> ./main.go:13: undefined: File

I'm sure this is one of those things that I don't know I don't know. What I do know:

- Per `os/file.go`, type of the return value I'm looking for is `*File`
- That type is defined in `os/file_unix.go` as a struct

Can someone explain to me:

1. How do I create an empty variable that can then be used to store the first variable in the results of `os.Create` and `os.Open`.
2. Why were my two attempts wrong?
3. Anything else that I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You could simplify the checking if a file exists then opening logic by just using `os.OpenFile(name, O_RDWR|O_CREATE, 0666)` ( the file will be created if it doesn't exist implicitly)

Comment: For ref, [documentation here](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile). +1 @AmmarBandukwala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining variable is `var <variable-name> <type>`, learn more [about variables](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/4).

```
var file *os.File
var err error
```

Your updated code:

```
func main() {
  path := "list.txt"

  var file *os.File
  var err error

  // Check if file exists
  if err = os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    file, err = os.Create(path)
  } else { // If file exists, open it
    file, err = os.Open(path)
  }

  // Check errors opening and creating file
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
  }

  // Defer closing file
  defer file.Close()
}
```

Comment: I tried `var file *File` but needed to define that it came from the `os` package. Thanks; this makes total sense.